# How can I sort on field of first or last document of an array of nested documents

Tags: mongodb

My document looks like this

```
{
  field1: somevalue,
  field2: some other value,


  nested_documents: [ // array of nested document
    { ip: , session_id: , datetime: }, // first nested document
    { ip: , session_id: , datetime: }, // second nested document

    // ...many more nested documents
  ]
},
```

Is it possible to get sorted documents on the basis of `datetime` field of the first,second or last document of the `nested_documents` array? If yes then how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for bothering with the question. I realized that there was a positional operator that could be used for querying arrays so tried that operator while sorting and it worked.

It can be done by using the positional operator. This is how i did it from the shell

```
sorting by the first nested document's field

   db.sample.find().sort({"nested_documents.0.field_name" : -1})   // for descending order sort

sorting by the second nested document's field

   db.sample.find().sort({"nested_documents.1.field_name" : -1})   // for descending order sort

Now for sorting by last document's field i have to keep track of length of the array so if length of array is 10 my query would be

   db.sample.find().sort({"nested_documents.9.field_name" : -1})   // for descending order sort
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-ArrayElementbyPosition) to sort by a specific index in the array:

```
db.foo.drop();

db.foo.insert({
    _id: 1,
    docs: [
        { date: new ISODate("2012-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
        { date: new ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
    ]
});

db.foo.insert({
    _id: 2,
    docs: [
        { date: new ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00Z") },
        { date: new ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
    ]
});

jsTest.log("Sorting by first embedded document's date, ascending");
db.foo.find({}, { "docs.date": 1 }).sort({"docs.0.date": 1}).forEach(printjson);

jsTest.log("Sorting by second embedded document's date, ascending");
db.foo.find({}, { "docs.date": 1 }).sort({"docs.1.date": 1}).forEach(printjson);
```

Comment: I didnt get `the dynamic position from an $elemMatch query is not available for sorting`.

Comment: My mistake. I meant to refer to the [dynamic positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) which lets you use `$` to refer to a field in your original query for updating. I only brought that up because it was mentioned in the other answer, which has since been deleted.